# Is an open internet access a productivity killer at the workplace?

Tags: productivity

I hear about workplaces banning sites like Facebook, or Twitter, all in the name of productivity gain.

Has there been any studies showing any evidence that having full access to browse the web at work a potential productivity killer?

Comment: At what *type* of job? As it stands, I don't think this is generally answerable. (A personal anecdote: StackOverflow (the grandparent of this site, amongst other things) has saved me, as a programmer, from reinventing *tens* of wheels (oh, and then there's developers.facebook.com, etc.). I'd posit that is a **potential productivity booster** (note the weasel word). OTOH, if your job is of the data-entry type, I understand how open internet access might distract you. See also: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/21535/what-is-the-right-level-of-site-blocking-for-you-as-a-developer )

Comment: I Think this question borders on the line of being equal to "is the Sky really blue?"  Its answerable.  But I think its pretty close to common knowledge.  You restrict access to avoid having to discipline people for misuse.  If your job function does not involve facebook and twitter then any time spent on them during work time is non productive.

Comment: @Chad: it's not obvious, as there have been some studies showing that **moderate** usage of non-work related webs actually increases overall productivity. To make a parallel: Do you have coffee breaks at work? Are you a professional coffee taster?

Comment: I have clients who had me block internet [web] access for most of the staff (e.g., whose job it is to answer phones and schedule services) because they were neglecting their work (and customers) due to being too engaged in chat rooms and games on FaceBook.  So, it definitely depends on the type of job one is doing.  I suspect the level of maturity of the worker is a major factor too.

Comment: @Vartec - Are you saying that everyone should always have access to Facebook and that will make people more productive?

Comment: @Chad: If you're saying that it will make them **less** productive, then prove it with peer reviewed study. *"Common knowledge"* is not an argument that is acceptable on Skeptics.SE.

Comment: No but time spent non-productively reduces productivity... that is the definition of it.  The the question here can nearly be boiled down to "Is the definition of productivity wrong?"  A specific claim like "everyone should always have access to Facebook and that will make people more productive" is a better skeptics claim.

Comment: @Chad: "time spent non-productively reduces productivity", so you're basically saying that people should have no breaks at all? Damn, even slaves had time to rest.

Comment: used to work in an environment where they blocked most anything. Research projects that could have been done in a few hours took weeks to complete. And that's becoming ever more common.

Comment: @Chad No, that is not the **definition** of productivity. Productivity *actually has a formal definition in economics*, and that is not it.

Comment: @Vartec - No I am saying that time spend on breaks is spend non productively.  Should time spent productively be the only thing one cares about in a work environment is a different question.  One I think would probably have an answer of no.

Comment: @Chad: productivity is not measured in time spent working, but in amount of work done during given time. And no one questions the fact, that productivity of 8h working straight w/o single break is much less than 8h with breaks.

Comment: @vartec - This question is not asking about breaks though.  Your productivity is measured over a time period.  If you measure over the period of a break you get no productivity.  This question is very bad subjective.

Comment: This is useless, since most people have smartphones.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found many research's papers addressing this question.

http://www.emeraldinsight.com/journals.htm?articleid=1865124&show=abstract

> The paper highlights that social networking technology can facilitate improved workplace productivity by enhancing the communication and collaboration of employees which aids knowledge transfer and consequently makes

http://www.netaddiction.com/articles/eia_new_trends.pdf

> In a survey of 1439 workers by Vault.com, an online
>   analyst firm, 37% admitted to surfing constantly at work, 32% surfed a few times a day, and 21% surfed a few times a week (Adschiew, 2000).

http://sigs.aisnet.org/sighci/icis03_wksp/hci03_program_proceedings.pdf#page=50

> Several
>   recent studies reveal much abuse of the Internet in the
>   workplace by employees; users exchange personal emails,
>   shop on line, check scores on sporting events,
>   gamble on line, view pornographic material, and chat on
>   instant messaging services.
>   In the most recent U.S. study (Colby and Parasuraman,
>   2002), it is estimated that employees spend between 3.7
>   and 6.5 hours per work week on personal Net use. Earlier
>   studies (Lim, 2002) revealed that between 64% and 90%
>   of U.S. workers engaged in personal activities while at
>   work. Financial losses from this abuse have been
>   estimated to reach 64% of organizations, costing $378
>   million in 2001 (Computer Security Institute, 2001).

Internet abuses (counseling):
http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/j.2161-1920.2003.tb00859.x/abstract

A book about Internet at workplace:
http://books.google.ca/books?hl=fr&lr=&id=SiOOeEBrxywC&oi=fnd&pg=PR11&dq=internet+productivity+workplace&ots=mtr2YHMeFR&sig=Wrv5kyGJ9eN99YyndlY33ohcc2Q#v=onepage&q=internet%20productivity%20workplace&f=false

In conclusion, there is clearly no scientific consensus today. More research would need to be done. The first paper showing increase of productivity do not prove that it is always the case. It proves that in the context they used, the social media were positive on productivity. However, it could have been very different in another context.

Comment: I need to add that the increase in productivity of the first paper is due to the increase in social interaction between employees. In fact, many papers demonstrates that workplaces with enhanced social ties perform better.

Answer (score 4):

It's not that obvious. ["PopCap Break" 2008 report](http://www.realwire.com/release_detail.asp?ReleaseID=8778) (original site doesn't exist anymore) suggests that:

> (... personal internet use in the workplace ...) is far from
>   distracting employees from their work, taking a 10-minute online break
>   during the course of the working day serves to reduce stress while
>   sharpening and refocusing the mind.

[Dr Chamorro-Premuzic](http://www.gold.ac.uk/psychology/staff/premuzic/) comments:

> “The report proves that a ten minute e-break a
>   day can have significant benefits but, despite this, many bosses are
>   banning them in the fear that they distract employees. By factoring in
>   a dedicated slot for an e-break bosses are fostering a more trusting
>   working environment, boosting productivity and ultimately increasing
>   their profit which surely makes good business sense.”

Comment: This does not address wether or not shutting off social media increases production.  It just shows that you can increase production through alternate methods... And it relies on anecdote for proof... This does not meet [Skeptics SE Standards for no original work](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/5/faq-must-all-answers-be-referenced/16#16)

Comment: @Chad: wrong. it's based on research by Dr Chamorro-Permuzic: http://www.gold.ac.uk/psychology/staff/premuzic/

Comment: Anecdotal research... And it still does not address the question of whether or not shutting off social media increases production.

Comment: One could argue that allowing 10 min a day is not the same as giving *ad libitum* access...

Comment: @nico: one could argue that **adults** would know not to abuse limitless coffee breaks, bathroom breaks, e-breaks. Of course there are companies, where you have no more than 300s of bathroom breaks a day etc. There are also companies, which limit internet access. Somehow these are not the companies with highest productivity.

Comment: @vartec: so what is the good limit? 10 minutes? 30 minutes? What if I stay on Facebook for 1 hour a day but then I work 1 hour later at night? What if I do six 5-min breaks over the day rather then one 30 min break? The policy where I work (but, then again, this is not applicable to all types of job) is: do your work and we're happy. I can go to work at 11am or at 5am, I can work nights, nobody cares as long as I do what I'm paid for.

Comment: @nico: so, what's your point exactly? you'd work better with FB blocked?

Comment: @vartec: no, my point is that saying that the fact that 10 min per day increases productivity is highly dubious. It depends on the person, on the type of job, on the general attitude in the workplace. It is not always true that imposing limitations increases productivity. It sometimes does, sometimes does not. I can easily not do my job without the need of being on Facebook. By giving me the freedom of browsing the web, as long as I do my job well, I feel that the workplace is a cool place, and I am more productive. But it does not necessarily apply to everyone.

Comment: @nico: The claim comes from a published study, so I don't understand how can it be "highly dubious" with the only argument to oppose it is Chad's "common sense". Especially that you confirm that in your case the conclusions from the study are correct - blocking internet decreases motivation, freedom increases it. Motivation increases productivity.

Comment: @vartec: I say that it is highly dubious that 10 minutes is better than 30 minutes or 1 hour or *ad libitum*. It depends on the situation. In that specific case it worked, but I would like to see a meta-analysis of multiple studies on the matter.

Comment: @nico: is the original question "does 10 minute e-break work better than 30 minute one?" or is it if blocking Internet access increases productivity?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1688/discussion-between-nico-and-vartec)

Comment: so the report was done by the folks who write the games?

Comment: @warren: first, even if it was, YPB? second, no, by psychology professor at University of London.

Comment: @vartec - if it's being done *by* the facebook games folks, they'll have a vested interested in stating that facebook does *not* have a negative impact on productivity :)

Comment: @warren: which proves what?